# fgets() and text files

Tags: c

My book mentions that `fgets` will read until it meets the (n-1)th character or a character of a new line. By character of new line do we only mean Enter (\n)? I am asking this because what I did was to create a text file on which I started typing in some nonsense, surpassing the character limit of each line meaning that I used more than one lines. After that I used `fgets` and what I expected was it to read only the characters in the first line of the text file but what it did was read all of them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char box[5000];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    fgets(box, 5000, fp);
    puts(box);
}
```

Test.txt (The text is random that's why it's silly) (285 characters):

```
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk25kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkggggggggggiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

So the result I expected was for it to print only part of the text and actually as many characters as the limit that is set for one line, minus one, (which I think is something above 250). But instead of that, it prints all of them. Note: The same thing happens even I type even more characters in the file.

Comment: Impossible to answer without setting your code. Please read this: [mre]

Comment: Yes, newline means `\n`. "but what it did was read all of them" Likely it means you have a bug in your code or you are misinterpreting the results. But we can't help with that unless you show the code, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Did you think of verifying you actually have a `\n` at the end of your lines, and not an `\r`?

Comment: Are you sure that the input is not just one line of text? Your editor may be auto-wrapping it so it may appear to be multiple lines to you. When I copy it into my editor it appears to be a single line. Did you ever press "enter" whilst typing that input?

Comment: @usr2564301 I've never heard or seen \r before.

Comment: @kaylum yes I actually thought of that and I doubled the text which was originally 285 characters and now it's 500+ and it still prints all of them.

Comment: But did you press "enter" at all? Your buffer is 5000 not 500.

Comment: I didn't press enter. That's what im wondering about. Does new line matter only if enter is pressed or is it considered a new line if it just surpasses the character limit of each line which i just read is 255 plus the \n. My question is, since there are more characters than that, isn't it considered more than one line and therefore shouldnt it only read 255 characters and not all of them?

Comment: Why do you think there's a limit "something above 250"? Your program can read a single line of up to 5000 characters. C doesn't impose a limit on line lengths for text files. If you increased the size of your array to one million, changed the argument to `fgets` accordingly, and ran your program with a million-character input file, it will probably handle it correctly. (I've committed some off-by-one errors here by failing to account for trailing `\n` and `\0` characters, but the idea is the same.)

Comment: "the character limit of each line which i just read is 255". Where did you read that from? Either you misunderstood or the reference is wrong.

Comment: @kaylum The OP doesn't need to press enter when reading from a file, and the book imposes the "limit" for some reason.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I think OP and I both understand that we are talking about inputting the text into a file when we refer to pressing enter. It makes no sense to be talking about "pressing enter" when writing code to read a file.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that the book imposes a limit? I suspect it's just saying that your program doesn't need to handle lines longer than 255 characters. You happen to have written a program that can handle a 5000-character line, and nothing in your book will prevent it from working on lines longer than 255 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming that there's an upper limit, perhaps 255 characters, on the length of a line in a text file. C imposes no such limit, except indirectly by using `int` as the size argument to `fgets`.

Your program defines a 5000-character array and calls `fgets` with a length argument of 5000. That means it can read a single line of up to 5000 characters (or close to that; I'm ignoring a couple of off-by-one issues for the `'\n'` and `'\0'` characters). The input line in your question is only 285 characters long, so your program will easily read it as a single line.

You can try changing the length of your array to see what happens when an input line is too long to fit:

```
char box[255];
...
fgets(box, sizeof box, fp);
```

Note that using `sizeof box` rather than repeating the number means the call won't get out of sync with the array size.

Comment: I think I can find a quote disproving "C imposes no such limit"; I think there's a maximum line length for a text file.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: By all means provide it. I'm reasonably sure you're mistaken. Some implementations might impose such a limit, the C standard does not. Text files with lines thousands of characters long are not uncommon. And the lack of such a limit neatly explains the behavior you're seeing. (The C standard does permit implementations to impose a limit on line length in C source files, but that's not relevant.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I just realized that my book sets this limit for each line of the text stream. But how is that different to what I'm saying?

Comment: It appears that the limits were in POSIX. I need to stop doing confusing those two...

Comment: @S.S.Anne: I think I found what you're referring to: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html `LINE_MAX` and `_POSIX2_LINE_MAX` apply to a *utility* "when the utility is described as processing text files". I believe they apply to utility programs specified by POSIX (`cat`, `grep`, etc.), not to C programs in general. `/bin/cat` is permitted to limit input lines to 2048 bytes (though most implementations don't). Your program can and does handle a 5000-byte input line. (Again, I'm ignoring some off-by-one issues.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, correct.

Answer (score 1):

It only stops at the newline character `\n` or at `n-1` characters. There is no newline character other than `\n`.

As you set the limit for your buffer and the amount `fgets` can read to `5000`, it can easily read all the characters in your file and print them.

There is no line length limit in ISO C (ISO/IEC 9899), whether one is imposed by your book or not. Your book is probably outdated.